# find + delete files that contain "."

Tags: linux, find, rm

I need to remove all the files under /tmp that contain the "." or dot character

so I created the following

```
find /tmp -name "*.*" -delete
```

please advice if this is the best approach to remove the files that contain "." ?

Comment: please show your approach by answer

Comment: @123: you don't need to escape `.`

Comment: hi cuonglm please advice if you think about better syntax , i also not sure what is better to use delete or rm ?

Comment: @cuonglm oh yeah.

Comment: @yael that's the best way, if your `find` supports `-delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Now for another generic method:

```
 find /tmp -type f -name '*.*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```